# Need to add alt tag for image Dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

1. I have a J.script like below and i want to add alt tag dynamically to
   the image(id="consumer Header") based on some conditions.
2. I have tried below ways like by giving id to div and set attribute but nothing works for me(consumer header is null).

   window.onload = getStrings();

   ```
   function getStrings()
   {                             
   var $consumerheader = document.getElementById("consumerheader"); 
   $consumerheader.setAttribute("alt", "R- Insurance");     
   var test = document.getElementById("consumerHeader").alt;
   alert("test");

   //var $img = $divconsumerHeader.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];   

   //control.setAttribute("consumerheader","R- Insurance")
   // var test1 = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
   // alert("test1");
    }
   ```

   ```
   <div id="divconsumerHeader" class="head" style="text-align: center;">
                   <img src="shared/images/headers/ConsumerOnline.png" id="consumerHeader" alt="" style="width: 177" />
   </div>
   ```

Comment: Have you tired calling the function on document load instead of in a function?

Comment: If that `window.onload = getStrings();` is part of the script it needs to be called after the function is created, not before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID of the Image in your HTML is `consumerHeader` and in Javascript you are using`consumerheader`. that's why its not working.

```
function getStrings()
{                             
var $consumerheader = document.getElementById("consumerheader");
//                                                     ^ Here is the issue make this "h" to "H"
$consumerheader.setAttribute("alt", "R- Insurance");     
var test = document.getElementById("consumerHeader").alt;
alert("test");

//var $img = $divconsumerHeader.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];   

//control.setAttribute("consumerheader","R- Insurance")
// var test1 = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
// alert("test1");
 }
```

**Note:** *Javascript is case sensitive*.
[**Here is an working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/krishanudey/qbFL4/2/)